# C# How to create Color spectrum (bitmap)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, colors

How can I create a bitmap that looks something like this?
[image: rectangle colorspectrum]

Rectangle picture. Bottom is for dark colors. Top is for bright colors. Colors are changing from left to right.

I need to create my own color spectrum bitmap because (external)image files are often compressed and not showing the correct colors in particular pixels.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493944/c-sharp-create-gradient-image) help?

Comment: [Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3152130+gradient) - _bottom is for dark colors. top is for bright colors_ You do know though, that color space is in 3d, right?

Comment: @TaW yoo those are helpful links. especially [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30339553/fill-panel-with-gradient-in-three-colors/30341521#30341521)